# How to display the computed value in the Textview

Tags: java, android, xml, textview

I am wondering why the pieces of code inside the public void onClick(View v) method is not working. When I click the button to calculate, the pop up box is displaying and it notifies me:

> The application has stopped unexpectedly

But there is no such error when I removed that pieces of code (inside the method public void onClick(View v) means that the problem is on that code and is not on the manifest file.

```
  import android.app.Activity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.*;

   public class Form2 extends Activity 
   {

    String str1="";
    String str2="";
    String str3="";
    String str4="";
    String str5=""; 
    String str6="";
    String totalString = null;
    double num1=0;
    double num2=0;
    double num3=0;
    double num4=0;
    double num5=0;
    double num6=0;
    double a=0;
    double b=0;
    double c=0;
    double total=0;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.form2);

      final  TextView nameTV=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.nameTV);
        nameTV.setText(getIntent().getExtras().getString("nameKey"));

        final TextView subjTV=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.subjTV);
        subjTV.setText(getIntent().getExtras().getString("subjectKey"));

        final TextView tv1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv1);

        final EditText firstETxt=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.et1);

        final EditText firstAETxt=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.et1a);

        final EditText secondETxt=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.et2);

        final EditText secondAETxt=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.et2a);

        final EditText thirdETxt=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.et3);

        final EditText thirdAETxt=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.et3a);



        ImageButton calcuButt=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.calcB);

        calcuButt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                if(v.getId()==R.id.calcB)
                {
                    str1=firstETxt.getText().toString();
                    num1=Double.parseDouble(str1);

                    str2=firstAETxt.getText().toString();
                    num2=Double.parseDouble(str2);

                    str3=secondETxt.getText().toString();
                    num3=Double.parseDouble(str3);

                    str4=secondAETxt.getText().toString();
                    num4=Double.parseDouble(str4);

                    str5=thirdETxt.getText().toString();
                    num5=Double.parseDouble(str5);

                    str6=thirdAETxt.getText().toString();
                    num6=Double.parseDouble(str6);

                    a=num1*num2;
                    b=num3*num4;
                    c=num5*num6;

                    total=a+b+c;

                    totalString = Double.toString(total);

                    tv1.setText(totalString);

            }}


        });

    }
}
```

and this is the xml code:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <AbsoluteLayout
    android:id="@+id/widget0"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:background="@drawable/bg"
    >
    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/widget33"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Enter all the scores you already have and"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:typeface="sans"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:layout_x="10px"
    android:layout_y="42px"
    >
    </TextView>
    <EditText
    android:id="@+id/et3"
    android:layout_width="57px"
    android:layout_height="35px"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:layout_x="10px"
    android:layout_y="232px"
    >
    </EditText>
    <EditText
    android:id="@+id/et1"
    android:layout_width="56px"
    android:layout_height="33px"
    android:textSize="13sp"
    android:layout_x="10px"
    android:layout_y="152px"
    >
    </EditText>
    <EditText
    android:id="@+id/et2"
    android:layout_width="55px"
    android:layout_height="34px"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:layout_x="10px"
    android:layout_y="192px" 
    >
    </EditText>
    <EditText
    android:id="@+id/et3a"
    android:layout_width="57px"
    android:layout_height="34px"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:layout_x="70px"
    android:layout_y="232px"
    >
    </EditText>
    <EditText
    android:id="@+id/et2a"
    android:layout_width="57px"
    android:layout_height="32px"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:layout_x="70px"
    android:layout_y="192px"
    >
    </EditText>
    <EditText
    android:id="@+id/et1a"
    android:layout_width="57px"
    android:layout_height="35px"
    android:textSize="13sp"
    android:layout_x="70px"
    android:layout_y="152px"
   >
   </EditText>

    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv1"
    android:layout_width="122px"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TextView"
    android:textColor="#ff000000"
    android:layout_x="120px"
    android:layout_y="162px"
    >
    </TextView>
    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv2"
    android:layout_width="128px"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TextView"
    android:textColor="#ff000000"
    android:layout_x="120px"
    android:layout_y="212px"
    >
    </TextView>
    <EditText
    android:id="@+id/ete"
    android:layout_width="98px"
    android:layout_height="37px"
    android:layout_x="120px"
    android:layout_y="242px"
    >
    </EditText>
    <TextView 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="#000000" 
    android:textSize="18sp" 
    android:text="SubjectTextView" 
    android:id="@+id/nameTV" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:textStyle="bold" 
    android:layout_x="13dip" 
    android:layout_y="122dip">
    </TextView>
    <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:textColor="#000000" 
    android:textSize="16sp" 
    android:text="the equivalent percentage of it in your subject" 
    android:typeface="sans" 
    android:id="@+id/widget34" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_x="13dip" 
    android:layout_y="74dip">
    </TextView>
    <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:textColor="#000000" 
    android:textSize="18sp" 
    android:text="nameTextView" 
    android:typeface="sans" 
    android:id="@+id/subjTV" 
    android:layout_width="144px" 
    android:textStyle="bold" 
    android:layout_x="48dip" 
    android:layout_y="32dip">
    </TextView>
    <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:textColor="#000000" 
    android:textSize="16sp" 
    android:text="Hi" 
    android:typeface="sans" 
    android:id="@+id/widget30" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_x="22dip" 
    android:layout_y="34dip">
    </TextView>
    <ImageButton android:id="@+id/calcB" 
    android:layout_height="36px" 
    android:layout_width="100px" 
    android:src="@drawable/calc" 
    android:layout_x="122dip" 
    android:layout_y="329dip">
    </ImageButton>
    </AbsoluteLayout>
```

Comment: Which line causes crash? Looks like str1-str6 or tv1 is null. Check this out

Comment: i've already edited it.

Comment: avoid `AbsoluteLayout`

Comment: why sir? could it be the AbsoluteLayout?

Comment: it is deprecated since API level 3. better to use `LinearLayout` or `RelativeLayout`

Comment: if you are getting error then put your `logcat` here

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the full code, the reason could be one of the following:

- Your `Double.parseDouble(strX)` calls can throw a `NumberFormatException` - if the string does not contain a parseable double. Meaning that you need to be sure that they all contain a valid value.
- One of your views is null, ie has not been initialized with a call such as `secondETxt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.YOURID);`

My guess is that one of your `EditText` views is empty, causing the above exception.

Comment: but all of the Edit text were not empty. pls. see it on my edited code above. Thanks :D

Answer (score 0):

I ran your code and it seems to have many problems. I will not give you advices like "avoid Absolute layout" or anything that you will learn your own in the future.

So , the first crash is at this line of code

```
nameTV.setText(getIntent().getExtras().getString("nameKey"));
```

So, if you are at the context of main activity, you don't have to get anything from the Intent class. The result will be always the same : crash
So, define first of all where are your values coming from.

Second ,you have to check the values that are in the editTexts before your parse them.They don't have to be null because you will get a NullPointerException and the values have to be at least numbers to avoid NumberFormatException.

At the end , the line of code

```
 if(v.getId()==R.id.calcB)
```

is not necessary.